# Trying to dismiss subview and UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm still very new to iOS developing. In fact, if there is a super noob, I would be one :p. Currently I am working on creating an `IBAction` button that accesses a subview. I have 2 ViewControllers, `AddClientVC` and `NewClientVC`, both with .nib files. So basically, inside my AddClientVC I implement an `IBAction` button with the following code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIView *transparentBG = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-5, -5, 1500, 2500)];
    transparentBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    transparentBG.opaque = NO;
    transparentBG.alpha = 0.5;
    [self.view addSubview:transparentBG];
    transparentBG.center = transparentBG.center;

    vc = [[NewClientVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewClientVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
    vc.view.center = self.view.center;
}
```

As you can see I implemented a UIView as a transparent background. Basically AddClientVC --> Transparent Background --> NewClientVC. Now I have created another IBAction button but this time inside NewClientVC as a function to dismiss the accessed subview which looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)saveDismiss:(id)sender
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The problem I'm having right now is when I click the saveDismiss button it only removes the subview that I called previously on AddClientVC but it didn't remove the transparent background I have created as a `UIView`. So the problem is how do I implement an action which simultaneously removes my subview and the `UIView` transparent background I created.

I need all the help I can get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not to manage your screens by adding subviews manually but instead use

```
- (void)presentModalViewController: (UIViewController *)modalViewController
                          animated: (BOOL)animated
```

method on your root viewController.
Or better instantiate a UINavigationController and use push and pop methods to drill down/up your views.
[See apple reference here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentModalViewController%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: i know i wanted to use presentModalView or UIPopviewController..but apparently someone insists on using adding a subview instead.

Comment: If your new view overlaps entirely the old one, using a viewController and pushing it on the stack is a good practice. Could you tell me the reason you think adding a subview is better ?

Comment: apparently its much more faster, when once its called the subview appears instantly without any delays whatsoever.

Comment: Do not worry about code execution speed and stay confident in apple's SDK. UIKit is optimized for best user experience. Trying to boost your code by doing inappropriate SDK use is, in my opinion, a risky strategy. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure I fully understand what you want to happen, but maybe you could try something like this?

```
- (IBAction)saveDismiss:(id)sender
{
    [vc removeFromSuperView];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: in the button pressed ibaction when its click you will get a subview from NewClient VC. Apparently i have to embedd a transparent UIView background before the subview of NewClient VC is called. Then when the subview is called, when save dismiss is click, i want it to dismiss the current view and goes back to the AddClientVC. But apparently when i implement [self.view removeFromSuperview]; it only removes the subview but the UIView transparent background is still there. I tried it but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

> Do not worry about code execution speed and stay confident in apple's SDK. UIKit is optimized for best user experience. Trying to boost your code by doing inappropriate SDK use is, in my opinion, a risky strategy. ;) – Vincent Zgueb

Sorry Vincent but I don't agree with you. I reached here because I want to implement an gesture that adds a sub-view for my view, which will be the navigation of my app.

```
[self.view addSubview:ctrl.view];
```

is faster presenting the view than

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:ctrl animated:NO]
```

and by the way, the solution to the topic in my case was:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:ctrl.view];
```